# What is the proper syntax for using the DISABLE_FK_CHECK option of the COPY command?

Tags: yugabytedb

How do we use the DISABLE_FK_CHECK option in the COPY command?

This does not work:

```
yugabyte=> \COPY xpctd_prtn_value FROM '/root/data.txt' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '|', DISABLE_FK_CHECK);
ERROR:  option "disable_fk_check" not recognized
LINE 1: ...value FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '|', DISABLE_FK...
                                                             ^
```

See doc [page](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/api/ysql/the-sql-language/statements/cmd_copy/#performance-tips-for-large-tables) for reference.

I am running:

```
yugabyte=> SELECT substring(version() from 'YB-([^\s]+)') AS "YugabyteDB Version";
 YugabyteDB Version
--------------------
 2.13.2.0-b0
(1 row)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That feature will be available on 2.15.0.0 that should be released next week: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/releases/release-notes/v2.15/#v2.15.0.0

See issue details https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/12478 for backport status.

Comment: Thanks! What is the ETA for 2.14 back port?

Comment: It's been backported to 2.14. The next release should have it. Note on how release versioning works: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/releases/